# Flutter: CocoaPods could not find compatible versions for pod "firebase_analytics":

Tags: firebase, flutter

As the title self explain CocoaPods giving error while running the application,

**Full Logs**

```
[!] CocoaPods could not find compatible versions for pod "firebase_analytics":
  In Podfile:
    firebase_analytics (from `.symlinks/plugins/firebase_analytics/ios`)

Specs satisfying the `firebase_analytics (from `.symlinks/plugins/firebase_analytics/ios`)` dependency were found, but they required a higher minimum deployment target.
```

Does anyone have any idea why it is coming, as it was working fine previously.

Answer (score 1):

in your pubspc.yml try to add dependencies:

```
  firebase_core: ^1.0.0
```

then open xcode ,
run the ios folder
this will solve your problem ,